# How to search for email addresses using Salesforce REST API?

Tags: rest-api, rest

I'm using Restforce and their example for looking for a string is this:

```
client.search('FIND {bar}')
```

I'd like to extend to look for a specific email address like this:

```
client.search('FIND {a@a.com}')
```

The problem is that this search is returning a lot of other records that don't match the string `a@a.com` at all! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly why this search string is being interpreted as you're seeing, but using double quotes should give you the right matches:

```
client.search('FIND {"a@a.com"}')
```

Comment: I have a problem when the query string is 'a+a@a.com'. It says it's a MALFORMED_SEARCH. Do you know what kind of escaping I need to do to make it right? What if I want to cover all possible invalid symbols for the query?

Comment: [Reserved characters](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm#i1423105) such as `+` need to be escaped with a backslash, and you'll need to escape that backslash for Ruby, so your query should be something like `client.search('FIND {"a\\+a@a.com"}')`